# Camel SSH route - escape characters

Tags: ssh, apache-camel

I have a very simple camel ssh route setup with Java DSL with only one pollCommand: `date +%s%3N` which should output the current timestamp. But the result is empty. However if the command is just `date` it works as expected. I am pretty sure that the problem is in `+` or `%` characters but URL encoding didn't help:

- `date%20%2B%25s%253N`
- `date %2B%25s%253N`
- `date +%25s%253N`
- `date %2B%s%3N`

nothing from above worked.

Below is the code snippet which I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultCamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("ssh://root:pswrd@192.168.12.12:22?delay=1000&pollCommand=date +s3N%0A")
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
                    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${body}");
        }
    });
    camelContext.start();
}
```

The version of Camel is **2.19.2**.

So how should I encode/escape the special characters from the parameter part (`+%s%3N`) of my command?

Comment: Please explain better what you do, and show more code where you use that date stuff, and also tell the version of Camel.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I updated my question.

Comment: You can use the RAW(xxx) syntax to tell Camel to use it as-is. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-password-options-on-camel-endpoints-without-the-value-being-encoded.html

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen! `date RAW(+%s%3N)` works, actually the problem is in `+` sign, everything which is after it is ignored, this is why I had an empty result - `date +` in terminal returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one more solution in addition to [@Claus Ibsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406429/claus-ibsen)'s

```
date RAW(+%s%3N)
```

As I thought the problem was in `+` sign. So I just need to do not use it in `pollCommand` which could be done by following command:

```
date $(printf "\x2b")%s%3N
```